# Ruby on Rails Authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to create a separate view for changing user password i don't how to do that.When I start I realize that it need different methods and may be some validations in model.
I need help how can I do this. I have no idea.What I need to include in controller , model and view.
I am also implementing "Enter old password to create new password".

Comment: Are you using Devise? Or did you roll your own authentication system?

Comment: I had implemented by own Authentication System.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to follow the RESTful principles.

Create a `PasswordsController` in your project with the actions `edit` and `update`.

Then create the `edit.html.erb` view with the form for the password change.

The validations in your model depend on your requirements.

Here is an example of this above:

**Controller:**

```
class PasswordsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user
  before_action :check_current_password, only: :update

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @user.update password_params
      flash[:success] = 'Password changed'
      redirect_to user_path  # Your user's profile for example
    else
      flash[:danger] = 'Error'
      render :edit
    end
  end

  private

  def password_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:password, :password_confirmation)
  end

  def set_user
    @user = current_user  # Your current user
  end

  def check_current_password
    unless @user.authenticate(params[:current_password])
      raise  # I would recommend you to work with exceptions here because you interrupt the process.
             # You can make it also a bit more specific if you define an exception class and just catch them.
    end
  rescue
    flash[:danger] = 'Current password incorrect!'
    redirect_to password_path(current_user)  # Redirect back to the change page
  end
end
```

**View:**

```
<!-- HTML skeleton is in application.html.erb -->

<%= form_for @user, url: password_path, method: :patch do |f| %>
  <%= text_field_tag :current_password %>

  <%= f.text_field :password %>
  <%= f.text_field :password_confirmation %>

  <%= f.submit 'Change password' %>
<% end %>
```

Assuming you have installed `bcrypt` gem and your user model has a field called `password_digest`, your model should like this.

**Model:**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_secure_password
end
```

This is a very simple implementation of a password change. I haven't tested it but it's just here to give you an idea how it works.

For more, see https://gist.github.com/thebucknerlife/10090014#steps

Comment: Thank You. But the problem is the user has to enter current password to create a new password.

Comment: Then add another field which requires the current password and check it in your controller before you update it. I will update my answer.